# Bootstrap Popover Border CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I want to increase the thickness of the Popover border using CSS. I managed to do it with this code, but it leaves the arrow with the old thin line. What is the CSS code to also increase the thickness of the Popover arrow so that it looks uniform?

```
.popover.bottom
  {
    border-top: 5px solid #000000;
    border-left: 5px solid #000000;
    border-right: 5px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Changing the border-width: of `.popover .arrow`

Comment: what is arrow in your case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the `border-width` of `.arrow`.

```
.popover>.arrow {
    border-width: 16px;
}
```

This would require re-positioning of the `:after` pseudo element and the `.arrow` element though.

Something like this would work well:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLkQL/)

```
.popover.bottom>.arrow:after {
    top:7px;
    border-bottom-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.popover.bottom>.arrow {
    margin-left:-5px;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    margin-top:-5px;
}
```

It's worth noting that you will need to change this positioning based on the position of the popover..

For instance, if you were styling `.popover.right`, (rather than `.popover.bottom`) you could use something like this:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6vmH/)

```
.popover.right>.arrow:after {
    left: 8px;
    bottom: -10px;
}
.popover.right>.arrow {
    left: -16px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    border-right-color: #000;
}
.popover>.arrow {
    border-width: 12px;
}
```

Comment: @zessx I was going to comment on yours, but I thought I might have missed something! :)

Comment: JoshC, Can you also explain what each CSS does? So that I know how to do it in the future. What is ".popover.right>.arrow:after" and ".popover.right>.arrow" ?

Comment: @JimC It would be best to open up your browser's development tool and inspect the DOM - this would give you a visual. The element `.popover.right>.arrow:after` is a pseudo element (essentially added via CSS).  The element `.popover.right>.arrow` happens to be the pseudo element's parent. It is basically the container element of the little arrow.